# TypeScript saves type as undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

```
class A {
    private static readonly letters: { [type: string]: any; } = { 'b' : B }

    public static check(): void {
        console.log(A.letters)
        let letters: { [type: string]: any; } = { 'b' : B }
        console.log(letters)
    }
}

class B extends A {

}

A.check()
```

Result:

```
{ b: undefined }
{ b: { [Function: B] check: [Function], letters: { b: undefined } } }
```

Why exactly is the first log is undefined?

Comment: Because the class which you reference (`B`) isn't defined upon assignment?

Answer (score 1):

As @E.Sundin wrote in his comment, class `B` doesn't exist when class `A` is evaluated.

You'll need to have a static initializer:

```
class A {
    private static readonly letters: { [type: string]: any; }

    public static init() {
        (this as any).letters = { 'b' : B }
    }

    ...
}

...

A.init()
A.check()
```

([code in playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=class%20A%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20private%20static%20readonly%20letters%3A%20%7B%20%5Btype%3A%20string%5D%3A%20any%3B%20%7D%0A%0A%20%20%20%20public%20static%20init()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20(this%20as%20any).letters%20%3D%20%7B%20'b'%20%3A%20B%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%0A%20%20%20%20public%20static%20check()%3A%20void%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20console.log(A.letters)%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20let%20letters%3A%20%7B%20%5Btype%3A%20string%5D%3A%20any%3B%20%7D%20%3D%20%7B%20'b'%20%3A%20B%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20console.log(letters)%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Aclass%20B%20extends%20A%20%7B%0A%0A%7D%0A%0AA.init()%0AA.check()))

Because you wanted `A.letter` to be `readonly` there's a cast of `this` to `any` otherwise the compiler complains about assignment to a read only property.

---

Another option is to assign an empty object and later populate it:

```
class A {
    public static readonly letters: { [type: string]: any; } = {};

    ...
}

class B extends A { }
A.letters["b"] = B;
```

But then `A.letters` needs to be public, you can move it outside of `A` to keep it "hidden":

```
const letters: { [type: string]: any; } = {};

class A { ... }
A.letters["a"] = A;

class B extends A { }
letters["b"] = B;
```